# brew works only in the current terminal and not found when i change the terminal

Tags: linux, path, homebrew

I'am trying to install brew on linux using

```
 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

then adding brew to the path using

```
test -d ~/.linuxbrew && eval $(~/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)
test -d /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew && eval $(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)
test -r ~/.bash_profile && echo "eval \$($(brew --prefix)/bin/brew shellenv)" >>~/.bash_profile
echo "eval \$($(brew --prefix)/bin/brew shellenv)" >>~/.profile
```

It works fine on the current opened terminal but when i change the terminal I get

```
Command 'brew' not found
```

Any Idea how to fix this?

Comment: What do you get when executing `echo $PATH`? Does it show `/home/linuxbrew/bin`?
You can manually add it to the file `.bashrc`

Comment: in .bashrc the path is
export PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"
export MANPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/man:$MANPATH"
export INFOPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/info:$INFOPATH".

when i execute echo $PATH, the returned value of the PATH is not the same in the current cmd and in the nw cmd. but both contain home/user/.linuxbrew/bin

Comment: I think you need to change the export PATH to `PATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"` (and not `$HOME/.linuxbrew...`)

Answer (score 2):

I found out the answer, it seems that I have to set the environment variable to

```
  export PATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"
```

and not

```
  export PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run
`export PATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"`
And simply restart the system.